# How to insert data & photo/image by using Ajax/Javascript in CodeIgniter in popup windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, controller, popup

I want to insert two images in my source code using CodeIgniter and ajax in popup windows. The source code is working normally in inserting text type but no so for the image type. 
I have already tried so many codes on the internet none of them are working and using popup windows. I really hope that anyone in here could help me to find the right code and adding in my code below. Thank you so much.
(I'm sorry for my bad English:D)

CONTROLLER:

```
public function create(){
  if(!isset($_POST)) {
    show_404();
  }
  if($this->newdata_m->create()){
    echo json_encode(array('ok' => true, 'msg' => '<div class="text-green"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Successful </div>'));
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('ok' => false, 'msg' => '<div class="text-red"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Failed<strong>0 (NOL)</strong>. </div>'));
  }
}
```

VIEW:

```
<div id="dialog-form" class="easyui-dialog" show= "blind" hide= "blind" modal="true" resizable="false" closed="true" buttons="#dialog-buttons" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" novalidate>
    <table><tr>
        <td>Title</td><td>:</td>
        <td><input id="title" name="title"></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Upload Photo 1</td><td>:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="photo1" name="photo1"></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Upload Photo 2</td><td>:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="photo2" name="photo2"></td>  
        </tr>   
    </table>    
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Dialog Button -->
<div id="dialog-buttons">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="save()">Save</a> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var url;
url = '<?php echo site_url('newdata/create'); ?>';
function save() {
var string = $("#form").serialize();

var title = $("#title").val();
   if(title == 0) {
     $.messager.show({
     title:'<div><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Warning ! </div>',
     msg: '<div class="text-red"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Sorry, title cannot be empty.</div>',
     timeout:2000,
     showType:'slide'
     });
     $("#title").focus();
     return false;
    }

$.ajax({
  type  : "POST",
  url: url,
  data  : string,
  success : function(result) {
  var result = eval('('+result+')');
  $.messager.show({
  title:'<div><i class="fa fa-info"></i> Information</div>',
  msg: result.msg,
  timeout:2000,
  showType:'slide'
  });
  if(result.ok) {
  jQuery('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
  $('#dg').datagrid('reload');
    }
  }
});
}
</script>
```

MODEL:

```
public function create() {
  $data = array(            
       'title'  => $this->input->post('title')
      );
  $this->db->insert('tbl_newdata', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Formdata()` function for javascript, like so:

```
myForm is form id
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
let formData = new FormData(myForm);
```